# Is it possible to dynamically create a page object element

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am using Cheezy's page-object gem. It works wonderfully in most cases but I can't seem to utilize it when working with dynamically created elements. I have a method for clicking on a cell by passing the text contents of the cell to the method and identifying the element at the time of action

```
def select_row (row_contents)
    cell(:row, :text => /#{row_contents}/i)
    self.row.click
end
```

I'm fairly sure this isn't working because the element is not having methods generated for it at run time. Can someone show me a way to create elements with page-objects dynamically in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def select_row (row_contents)
    self.class.cell(:row, :text => /#{row_contents}/i)
    self.row_element.click
end
```

The change is, the `cell` method should be called on the `class` of the `pageobject` since it is a class level method

Comment: You should be careful about doing this since all instances of this page object will now have this `row` element.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can locate elements similar to Watir by using the [NestedElements](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/NestedElements#cell_elements-instance_method). Your method could be simply written as:

```
def select_row(row_contents)
  cell_element(:text => /#{row_contents}/i).click
end
```